# Limits of Integral two possibilities?

Tags: integration

I have a quick question regarding the limits of an integral. Let's say that you are integrating a function (it doesn't matter too much which function - at least I think) between $1$ and $9$. However, in order to do this you need to make the substitution $x = (u + 1)^2$

Well, for the limit of '$x=1$' this is nice and easy, $u$ is $0$ in this case. However for $x=9$, you could have both $u=2$ or $u=-4$.

Which would you choose and why?

Thanks!

Comment: You could argue the same thing for $x=1$ as well, it can be that $u=-2$.

Comment: True, so what's going on?

Comment: $x$ is the original variable and $u$ is what you're defining to substitute, right?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber yes that's correct :)

Comment: If it is possible to treat it as $\sqrt{x}=u+1$ in the context then you should do that

Comment: @HenryLee would it not be plus or minus the square root of x though?

Comment: not if you define it initially in this way

Comment: Actually I think it depends on the question you are trying to solve.

Comment: Let $f$ be continuous on $[1, 9]$, $I = \int_1^9 f(x) dx$ and $g(u) = 2 f((u + 1)^2) (u + 1)$. Strictly speaking, $I \neq \int_{-4}^0 g(u) du$, because the rhs requires evaluating $f$ on $[0, 1]$, where we know nothing about $f$. However, $I = \int_0^2 g(u) du = \int_{-4}^{-2} g(u) du$, and, provided that $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ as well, $\int_{-2}^0 g(u) du = 0$.